# maven shade plugin exclude artifactset does not work

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am using maven shade plugin to build a uber jar. But, I want to exclude log4j-sl4j12 jar as it is creating conflict in my storm cluster. I am using the below plugin to exclude the jars.

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactSet>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </artifactSet>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass>com.org.SomeClass</mainClass>
                    </transformer>
                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now, when I execute maven package, the log shows that it is actually excluding the jars. 
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.7.12 from the shaded jar.
[INFO] Excluding org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.12 from the shaded jar.

However, my final jar still has these class files. I know an alternate solution where I can exclude  the jars from dependencies, but for this, I will have to know every dependency that has the slf4j jars and exclude it from each of them explicitly.  Can anyone please explain why the exclude artifactSet does not work?

Comment: Wildcards for exclusions are supported only since version 1.3 of the plugin. What version are you using?

Comment: maven 3.3.3. But, it doesnt work even without wildcards - even if I give 
<exclude>org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12</exclude>

Comment: The Maven version is irrelevant, it is the version of the `maven-shade-plugin` that matters.

Comment: maven-shade-plugin version is 2.4.1

Comment: I also see that if I trigger the package build from parent module, its working fine. However, when I trigger from the child module, it does not exclude the artifacts.

Comment: It feels like there is a bug in the plugin. You should report in the tracker.

Comment: Having the same exact issue. Executing from parent module does not fix it.